# Modify DOM of a template of a directive that have an ng-repeat with attribute set runtime

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I must add a css class to an element of the dom that is created inside a ng-repeat. The css class must be add just if a condition is verified. The condition is checked on an attribute that has the value calculated according to the item processed in the ng-repeat.

I let you see the code to be clearer.

Here my directive:

```
intranet
    .directive('emitLastRepeaterElement', function () {
        return function (scope) {
            if (scope.$last) {
                scope.$emit('LastRepeaterElement');
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('scVerticalMenu', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/Angular/Directives/VerticalMenu/verticalMenu.html',
            scope: {
                internalSiteMenu: '=ngModel' //two-way data-binding
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$on('LastRepeaterElement',
                    function () {
                        //Recupero l'ultimo link del menu interno di livello 2 che non abbia figli
                        //(L'ultimo link non deve avere il bordo nero inferiore)
                        var level2 = element.find("li[role=menuitem]:has(.level2):last");
                        var level3 = element.find("li[role=menuitem]:has(.level3)");
                        if ($(level2).next(level3).length == 0) {
                            $(level2).addClass('last');
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    });
```

Here the template:

```
<ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" role="menu" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;" ng-repeat="menu in internalSiteMenu" emit-last-repeater-element>
        <a class="level{{ menu.Level }} static" href="{{ menu.Url }}" tabindex="-1">{{ menu.Name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have found here, in stackoverflow a solution. When I execute the last loop of the ng-repeat I emit an event. It works partially. I go inside the `link` function but I cannot find the objects. I debugged.
It look likes that inside the `link` function the class of the anchor is still `class="level{{ menu.Level }}"` and not yet `class="level2"` or `class="level3"`

I think my approach is wrong. Perhaps I have to find another solution.
Do you have suggestion?

Thank you

**UPDATE**
Exactly I have a menù that have more levels:

```
menu
    item 1
        item 1.2
        item 1.3
        item 1.4
    item 2
        item 2.1
        item 2.2
    item 3
```

I want to add a class to every last item for each level. So in my example I want to add the class here:

```
menu
    item 1
        item 1.2
        item 1.3
        item 1.4 <-- addClass: last of item 1
    item 2
        item 2.1
        item 2.2 <-- addClass: last of item 2
    item 3 <-- addClass: last of menu
```

**UPDATE 2**
I use the directive inside the _layout.cshtml page.. In this way:

```
<div ng-controller="menuController" ng-init="getMenu">
    <sc-vertical-menu ng-model="siteMenu"></sc-vertical-menu>
</div>
```

The menuController call the back end to obtain the menù and put the result inside $scope.siteMenu

Comment: Looks over engineered to me. Where does the `scope.$last` come from? Do you want to add last class to the last element from the ng-repeat?

Comment: I have updated the post. I want to add the class to every last element of one level of the menu. I have the code that do this (that one inside the `link` function. It works if I do not use angularjs (with pure jQuery it works). But now that I moved everything in a directive, it does not work anymore ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umL03t49/1/

Just use your `scVerticalMenu` controller to detect which items are last:

```
intranet
    .directive('scVerticalMenu', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/Angular/Directives/VerticalMenu/verticalMenu.html',
            scope: {
                internalSiteMenu: '=ngModel' //two-way data-binding
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.internalSiteMenu.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (scope.internalSiteMenu[i].level > scope.internalSiteMenu[i + 1].level) {
                        scope.internalSiteMenu[i].last = true
                    }
                }
                scope.internalSiteMenu[scope.internalSiteMenu.length - 1].last = true
            }
        }
    });
```

Then use `ng-class` to display the `last` class

```
<ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" role="menu" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" ng-class="{'last': menu.last}" style="position: relative;" ng-repeat="menu in internalSiteMenu">
        <a class="level{{ menu.Level }} static" href="{{ menu.Url }}" tabindex="-1">{{ menu.Name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it gives me an error:

`Multiple directives [scVerticalMenu, ngController] asking for new/isolated scope on: <ul class="level1 static"... ng-controller="list_controller" ng-model="verticalMenu">`

Comment: Where's `scVerticalMenu` directive? Could you share it's code and the html code where it's used?

Comment: I have updated the question. However, scVerticalMenu is the directive I am creating and that you can see in the original post

Comment: Oh. I changed the answer. Turns out you don't need the controller since the whole thing is a directive. Just go through the items in your directive and detect which of them are last.